# Parsley.js: Multiple group validation

Tags: parsley.js

I am currently using Parsley.js 2.2.0. I had group validation working when there was one group, but I added another group, but it still tries to validate the old group.

eventinfo group example.

```
<input maxlength="45" value="" type="text" name="address" id="Address" class="form-control floatlabel" placeholder="Address" tabindex="75" title="Address" data-parsley-required data-parsley-group="eventinfo">
```

call to validate eventinfo group

```
if (elEventForm.parsley().validate('eventinfo') === false) { return }
```

quoteinfo group example.

```
<input data-parsley-required data-parsley-group="quoteinfo" maxlength="75" value="" type="email" name="email" id="Email" class="form-control floatlabel" placeholder="Email" tabindex="45" title="Email">
```

call to validate quoteinfo group

```
if (elEventForm.parsley().validate('quoteinfo') === false) {
      return
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

There have been **20 releases** since 2.2.0.

Current API is `...validate({group: 'eventinfo'})`

Comment: yes I know, but there has been lots of deprecation and I don't have time to change it all. But just to test, I swapped in the new code and tested with the current API and still got the same result.

Comment: Deprecation warning mean it should still work (until 3.0). Good luck.

Comment: Good luck? That's it? It doesn't work for me so I am SOL?